# Printing string twice on the same line using different alignments

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to print strings on a single line with different alignments. I'd like to print:

```
---> text <---          ---> text <---
```

I did:

```
lineWidth = 40
str = "---> text <---"
puts str.ljust lineWidth str1.center lineWidth
```

I received an error message:

```
in `<main>': undefined method `lineWidth' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use more parentheses and commas.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you provide an example?

Comment: For example, `str.ljust(lineWidth)` instead of `str.ljust lineWidth`. Your code, in its current form, is parsed as `puts(str.ljust(lineWidth(str1.center(lineWidth))))`. Not quite what you want, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
puts str.ljust(lineWidth/2) + str.rjust(lineWidth/2)
```

Comment: When answering, provide more than code. Explain/teach why that's appropriate. Also, it's good to correct improper use of the language. `lineWidth` is not the Ruby-way, `line_width` is.

Answer (score 1):

As @SergioTulentsev said, Ruby interpreter reads your code as:

```
puts(str.ljust(lineWidth(str1.center(lineWidth))))
```

You'll need to use parentheses to distinguish one `puts` call from another:

```
puts(str.ljust(lineWidth))
puts(str.ljust(lineWidth))
```

Comment: Yep, fixed the answer

Answer (score 1):

`printf` and `format` are excellent at outputting multiple variables on a single line:

```
irb(main):006:0> lineWidth = 40
=> 40
irb(main):007:0> str = "---> text <---"
=> "---> text <---"
irb(main):008:0> printf("%s%s\n",str.ljust(lineWidth), str.center(lineWidth))
---> text <---   

                                ---> text <---
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are three more ways of doing that.

```
str = "---> text <---"
line_width = 40
```

**#1**

```
puts str + " " * (line_width - 2 * str.length) + str

---> text <---            ---> text <---
0         1         2         3         4
```

**#2**

```
s = " " * line_width
  #=> "                                        "
s[0, str.length] = s[-str.length..-1] = str
puts s

---> text <---            ---> text <---
0         1         2         3         4
```

**#3**

```
s = str * 2
  #=> "---> text <------> text <---"
s.insert(str.length, " " * (line_width - 2 * str.length))
puts s

---> text <---            ---> text <---
0         1         2         3         4
```

or (a variant)

```
s = str * 2
s[str.length, 0] = " " * (line_width - 2 * str.length)
puts s

---> text <---            ---> text <---
0         1         2         3         4
```

Comment: this is very helpful, thanks